# Text mining and extracting words

Tags: r, text-mining, text-extraction

I am trying to extract table names from a SQL statement in R. For example, I would import SQL queries into R, and one row would contain:

```
SELECT A , B
FROM Table.1 p
JOIN Table.2 pv
ON p.ProdID.1 = ProdID.1
JOIN Table.3 v
ON pv.BusID.1 = v.BusID
WHERE SubID = 15
ORDER BY v.Name;
```

In R, I have been trying to use strsplit to the SQL statement that splits every word into a column, creating a data-frame and then finding the match to the word "from" and extracting the next word which would be Table.1.

I am having trouble on how to extract the other tables from multiple Joins or if there is a more efficient way or a package I haven't come across during my research. Any help would be much appreciated !

Comment: try using parsename https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way using regular expressions:

```
lines <- strsplit("SELECT A, B
                   FROM Table.1 p
                   JOIN Table.2 pv
                   ON p.ProdID.1 = ProdID.1
                   JOIN Table.3 v
                   ON pv.BusID.1 = v.BusID
                   WHERE SubID = 15
                   ORDER BY v.Name;", split = "\\n")[[1]]

sub(".*(FROM|JOIN) ([^ ]+).*", "\\2", lines[grep("(FROM|JOIN)", lines)]) # "Table.1" "Table.2" "Table.3"
```

Broken down:

```
# Use grep to find the indeces of any line containing 'FROM' or 'JOIN'
keywords_regex <- "(FROM|JOIN)"
line_indeces <- grep(keywords_regex, lines) # gives: 2 3 5
table_lines <- lines[line_indeces] # get just the lines that have table names

# Build regular expression to capture the next word after either keyword
table_name_regex <- paste0(".*", keywords_regex, " ([^ ]+).*")

# The "\\2" means to replace each match with the contents of the second capture 
# group, where a capture group is defined by parentheses in the regex
sub(table_name_regex, "\\2", table_lines)
```

Comment: I have been trying to get familiar with using sub in this way from previous googling. Do you have any documentation on using this the way you did? I would like this understand what's going on inside the Sub  function.  Thank you for the the help this is very helpful

Comment: When you say "using sub in this way" do you mean the regular expression?  (eg, the arcane-looking ".*(FROM|JOIN) ([^ ]+).*" he supplied as the pattern argument) . If so, this resource looks pretty good: https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/an-introduction-to-regular-expressions

Comment: I have broken down my answer a little more. I agree with HarlandMason that you should read a respected source to learn about regular expressions (which are complicated), but overall `sub` is as simple as replacing what the first argument matches with the second argument.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the explanation! I'll read the resource you sent me as I will need to get more familiar with this.